# error while creating cube in oracle awm

Tags: oracle, olap-cube

I'm working with ORACLE AWM to create my first cube. Trying to create it, ORACLE returns me the following error message:

```
Si è verificato un errore sul server
Classe di errore: Errore di Express
Descrizioni errore server:
INI: errore durante la creazione di un definition manager, Generico in TxsOqConnection::generic<BuildProcess>
INI: XOQ-01600: Errore DML OLAP "ORA-35571: Il numero massimo di errori di caricamento che si sono verificati." durante l'esecuzione del DML "SYS.AWXML!R11_LOAD_MEASURES('INCIDENTI.CUBE'  SYS.AWXML!___R11_LONG_ARG_VALUE(SYS.AWXML!___R11_LONG_ARG_DIM 1)  SYS.AWXML!___R11_LONG_ARG_VALUE(SYS.AWXML!___R11_LONG_ARG_DIM 2)  SYS.AWXML!___R11_LONG_ARG_VALUE(SYS.AWXML!___R11_LONG_ARG_DIM 3) 'NO')", Generico in TxsOqStdFormCommand::execute

at oracle.olapi.data.source.DataProvider.callGeneric(Unknown Source)
at oracle.olapi.data.source.DataProvider.callGeneric(Unknown Source)
at oracle.olapi.data.source.DataProvider.executeBuild(Unknown Source)
at oracle.olap.awm.wizard.awbuild.UBuildWizardHelper$2.construct(Unknown Source)
at oracle.olap.awm.ui.SwingWorker$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

How can I proceed to solve my problem?
Thanks to all